# Internet Explorer Out Of Memory Highcharts Highstock JQuery

Tags: jquery, highcharts

We are using Highstock to render graph information which we display to our client base. In Internet Explorer some of the graphs we load, with relatively large data sets, display the following issue:

SCRIPT7: Out of memory 
jquery.min.js, line 4 character 26028

While Chrome and Firefox work correctly we have consistently received this error while using Internet Explorer. It seems that IE is getting stuck in a loop and fails.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue to this and developed a work-around? We have tried optimizing some of the extra features of HighStock so the graph is bare-bones as far as stylized display but that has not resolved this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which version(s) of IE?  I'm not sure how you're loading the data into the chart, but if you're using ajax IE sucks compared to other browsers when handling huge amount of returned data with this method.

Comment: How much data? as it stands it looks like you're hitting a limitation of the browser/system you're working on. The only way of fixing it would be to 1: improve the system, 2: improve the browser, 3: reduce the amount of data being handled at a time.

Comment: We are testing both IE8 and IE9 and experiencing the same issue in both, although IE9 does tend to be better at handling the data. Also after installing the Google Chrome plug-in the prefermance improved, but only if the graph was able to load. The text files we use to import the datasets are about 800Kb but can potentially be larger, as we plot on 5 charts about a point every few seconds for 7+ hours.

Comment: Highcharts is a beautiful piece of software but I gave up on using it for high "density" applications (my current work involves 5 charts * 24 curves * 50 points per curve - and the memory usage was just too much).  This will always be a limitation of SVG drawing.  Each point, each line segment, each piece of the graph is a relatively complex object sitting in memory.

Comment: DataGrouping should help in such cases, however, you can aso try to use [lazy-loazding](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts) solution to load huge amount of points.